# Get average of user distinct best score

Tags: mysql

I have a MYSQL-Table which stores scores.
Every time a user improves a new entry is inserted into the table.

Example of the table:

```
| userID |  time  | gameID |
|--------------------------|
|   u1   |    3   |  game1 |
|   u1   |    2   |  game1 |
|   u2   |    3   |  game1 |
|   u3   |    3   |  game1 |
|   u1   |    3   |  game2 |
|   u2   |    1   |  game2 |
```

I would like to query the table and get a table looking like this.

```
| gameID |  min_time  | avg_time |
|--------------------------------|
| game1  |      2     |   2.66   |
| game2  |      1     |   2.00   |
```

I need the minimum time per gameID and the average time which only consists of each users minimum time per game (If a user played game1 three times only the best (shortest) should be used for the average with other users).

Is this possible with a MYSQL query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
    gameID
  , MIN(min_time) AS min_time
  , AVG(min_time) AS avg_time
FROM
    ( SELECT
          gameID
        , MIN(time) AS min_time
      FROM 
          tableX
      GROUP BY
          gameID
        , userID
    ) AS x
GROUP BY
    gameID
```